# Kendo Grid Won't Bind via Ajax

Tags: c#, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I am following the instructions for doing Ajax databinding using the Kendo Controls for ASPNET-MVC. However the Grid will not bind the returned data. I can see in Chrome that data is being returned from the AJAX call; the problem is that it won't bind. I am also using .ToDataSourceRequest to format the returned data.

Any ideas?

In my View

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                .Name("MonthFilter")
                .BindTo(Model.MonthDropdownOptions())
                .DataTextField("Text")
                .DataValueField("Value")
                .Events(e => e.Change("onMonthFilterChange"))
                )

      @(Html.Kendo().Grid<PersonStatus>()
            .Name("measuresGrid")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(c => c.PersonId).Width(100).Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(false).SuggestionOperator(FilterType.Contains).Operator("contains"))).HtmlAttributes(new { title = "#=Measure.Name#" });
                columns.Bound(c => 
c.PersonName).ClientHeaderTemplate("Patient Name").Filterable(ftb => 
ftb.Cell(cell => cell.ShowOperators(false).SuggestionOperator(FilterType.Contains).Operator("contains"))).HtmlAttributes(new { patientName = "patientName" });
            })
            .DataSource(ds =>
                ds.Ajax()
                .PageSize(20)
                .ServerOperation(true)
                .Read(read => read.Action("PersonRead", "PersonList").Data("getPersonGridParameterData"))
                .Model(m => m.Id(p=>p.PersonId))
            )
        )

    var getPersonGridParameterData = function (e) {
        console.log("Gettting parameter Data....");
        var monthFilterValue = $("#MonthFilter").val();
        return { "yearMonth": monthFilterValue };
    }
```

In my Controller`

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var viewModel = new PersonViewModel
        {
            People = new List<Person>()
        };

        viewModel.PeopleStatuses = GetPersonStatus();
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PersonRead([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, string yearMonth)
    {
        return Json(GetPersonStatus(yearMonth).ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }        


    private List<PersonStatus> GetPersonStatus(string yearMonth = "")
    {
        var aQuery = new PersonListQuery(yearMonth);
        var aResult = _queryDispatcher.Dispatch<PersonListQuery, PersonListQueryResult>(aQuery);

        return aResult.PeopleStatuses;
    }
```

Comment: Is that a typo? You are calling PersonRead, but your action is MeasuresRead.

Comment: @SteveGreene yes that is a typo; I've updated the code so as not to place the companies code in the public.

Comment: Updated to PersonRead

Comment: Are you hitting that action in debug? Any console errors?

Comment: Also, maybe start with a simple, single bound column then add the filterable stuff later.

Comment: I am hitting that action in Debug. Also, it returns actual data, and it formats it as well using ToDataScourceResult. I have also removed the Filterable bits. Still the same problem. It seems to be that for some reason, the Grid will not bind to the Ajax data.

Comment: This is just a hunch, hence a comment not an answer (tho I'll post it as an answer if it turns out true):  your 'return' statement in PersonRead is using 'ToDataSourceResult', which is synchronous. Whereas AJAX is asynchronous. Try awaiting 'ToDataSourceResultAsync' instead.  Either that, or in the grid html code specify the data source before the columns.

Comment: Tried Async and also placed the DataSource before the column list. Still no luck. Those are good ideas though.

Comment: If you are actually using ASP.NET Core, check this out: http://www.telerik.com/forums/json-serialization-breaks-grid

Comment: @dimodi serialization was the answer. If you add an answer I can give you the credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON serialization in ASP.NET Core uses lowercase keys by default, so the Grid data will be served with keys `"data"` and `"total"`. On the other hand, the Kendo UI MVC Grid expects uppercase keys for historical reasons and compatibility with ASP.NET MVC (`"Data"`, `"Total"`). In order to revert to uppercase keys, please follow the approach at

http://www.telerik.com/forums/json-serialization-breaks-grid#1N43h6vKUEmdhFLmYQd3yg

or

http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-core/getting-started/getting-started
(point 4)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this blog post: https://coderulez.wordpress.com/2017/05/12/asp-net-core-and-kendo-grid/

In ASP MVC what you did would have been enough. However in ASP.NET Core you need to take an additional step for the kendo grid to be able to read the data (see Startup.cs code below).

This is because ASP.NET Core incorporated Newtonsoft’s JSON Serializer and for some reason decided to set the default behavior to change the casing of our properties to camelCase (using CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver). In order to force it to use the same property names that we defined in our view models we need to use add the following line to Startup.cs:
[image: Startup.cs Config]

For more info about who is to blame for the decision of making camelCase the default :P take a look at:

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4283

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4842

Comment: camelCase is a Javascript standard, and is the normal casing of JSON properties. So the blame isn't really on MS, but on Kendo for not supporting it easily.